# MS Outlook Version 16.16 doesn't show calendar event reminders

Tags: macos, ms-office, calendar

For some or other reason MS Outlook doesn't show reminders when calendar events occur.

Generally, my meetings' reminders are configured for 15 minutes before events occur, however I never ever get any popup reminders that events are about to occur.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

- Microsoft Outlook for Mac Version 16.16
- Product ID: 03109-000-000001
- macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mac version of Outlook actually has an app that is in charge of displaying/sounding reminders, so it is nothing that you can access outside of Outlook.

If you launch Outlook and go to the Outlook menu the fourth item down should say either "Turn off reminders," or "Turn on reminders."

If it is the former you may want to reinstall Outlook as something has happened to cause the reminder application to not work. If it is the latter... well, problem solved.